# Reason for one code snippet working but not the other

Tags: c, compiler-errors

The following code snippet works:

```
main( )
{
    struct book
    {
        char name[20];
        int noof;
        float prices;
    };
    struct book b={0};
    printf("%d %f", b.noof, b.prices);
}
```

Here, I `name[ ]` is being intialised to 0. But the following code snippet does not work:

```
   main( )
   {
    char c[ ]=0;
    printf("%c", c[0]);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `0` in:

```
char c[ ]=0;
```

Is not a valid array initializer.  You need to put braces around it:

```
char c[] = { 0 };
```

Or, equivalently:

```
char c[] = "";
```

When you try to print, `%c` won't work either, since character `0` is normally unprintable.  Try with `%d`.

```
printf("%d\n", c[0]);
```

Aside from all that, your `main` function should be declared to return `int`.